# Use Unity3d particle system in UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've read a few different posts on how to display the particle system on the canvas in Unity but I don't seem to be understanding it.

I'm trying to use the Particle Ribbon asset by Moonflower in my UI but can't get it to display in the UI. I tried adding another Canvas as suggested in other posts, with Render mode set to Screen-Space Camera but no luck.
At one point I saw the particle system but it was very, very small and wouldn't change size regardless of scaling.

Comment: If any answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right one. _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 1):

you can set sortingOrder

ParticleSystemRenderer.sortingOrder / sortingLayerID,  Canvas.overrideSorting / sortingOrder / sortingLayerID

[canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm6P4.jpg)

[particle System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsbCF.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying the **UIParticleSystem** script found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions).

Generally speaking, this *Unity UI Extension* repository is full of amazing things created (and often updated) by the community : I'd advise you to bookmark it :)